# Fetch chunks of an array using a stateful offset

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to get a set of array elements through a range of values.

If I had the following array:

```js
const arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", ...]
```

And if I wanted to get only the first four elements, I would do it as follows:

```js
arr.slice(0, 4)
// output: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

But I would like to have the next four elements, that is, I would like my output to be as follows:

```js
// output: ["five", "six"]
```

But I would like to make it dynamic, like this:

```js
// first set of data (first four)
getData(1)
// second set of data (next four)
getData(2)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: That's a bad design because it requires mutating hidden global state (that being the current offset into the array). You should always avoid hidden state when writing software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` function could call `slice` using `(num - 1) * 4` as the first argument and `num * 4` as the second argument:

```js
const arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]

function getData(offset) {
  return arr.slice((offset - 1) * 4, offset * 4);
}

console.log(getData(1), getData(2));
```

Comment: `num` should be named `offset` so its purpose is clear.

Comment: I can get on board with that

Comment: `getData(1), getData(2)` will both return data from the same initial offset - I think the OP wants `getData` to behave more like the (awful) C `strtok` function. I suppose it could be done with `splice` instead of `slice`, but no-one should be using `splice` thesedays...

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that requirement from his post re: mutating the array